# Using 9DOF Sensor Stick EKF

Tags: ros, imu, navigation, robot-pose-ekf, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using a 9DOF Sensor Stick https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10724.
9DOF Razor https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10736 has a dedicated controller to compute orientation whereas I am only getting raw sensor data from 9 DOF Sensor Stick. I am interfacing the 9DOF Sensor stick with an Arduino Mega which also shares its resources interfacing with encoders, motor drive commands and pan-tilt servos. It appears that implementation of DCM or kalman filter on the Arduino is exhausting its resources. Unfortunately, I only have on Arduino. Is it possible use the 9DOF Sensor Stick with raw sensor readings from it? Based on http://answers.ros.org/question/9429/what-imus-work-with-ros/ , I expect the answer is NO. Please correct me, if I am wrong.
Could you please suggest pointers on how to integrate this sensor stick into robot_pose_ekf?

Thanks in advance,
B

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205992/using-9dof-sensor-stick-ekf/) by [bikram.adhikari](https://answers.ros.org/users/18966/bikram.adhikari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can publish the raw data to ROS and use the AHRS (madgwick's filter) in [imu_tools](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools) to process the data on the PC side.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bikram.adhikari](https://answers.ros.org/users/18966/bikram.adhikari/) on 2015-03-26**:
Thanks for the reference. I will post once I get the filter working.
Thanks again!
B